# java class only declaration no definition

Tags: java, android, android-webview

New to Java and debugging the WebView android app which does not update properly. To find out what happens in onDraw() of WebView the source code here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/webkit/WebView.java?av=f

shows the onDraw() class calls

```
 mProvider.init(javaScriptInterfaces, privateBrowsing);
```

the  **mProvider.init(...)** is here 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/webkit/WebViewProvider.java#WebViewProvider.init%28java.util.Map%2Cboolean%29

But only declaration is present no definition. In c++ the definitions are in cpp files. Is there any equivalent in java ?.

Comment: Yes, it's called an `interface` if you look at the whole file in the second link you'll notice that it's not defined as a `class` but rather a `interface` which then other `classes` can provide implementation for the definitions defined in the `interface`

Comment: Thanks. Where is mProvider object created. There is no definition in the first link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mProvider.init(javaScriptInterfaces, privateBrowsing);
```

Is implemented by `WebViewClassic`

The relevant grepcode link is [here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/webkit/WebViewClassic.java#WebViewClassic)

In case link is not available here is the raw method:

```
@Override
public void init(Map<String, Object> javaScriptInterfaces, boolean privateBrowsing) {
    Context context = mContext;

    // Used by the chrome stack to find application paths
    JniUtil.setContext(context);

    mCallbackProxy = new CallbackProxy(context, this);
    mViewManager = new ViewManager(this);
    L10nUtils.setApplicationContext(context.getApplicationContext());
    mWebViewCore = new WebViewCore(context, this, mCallbackProxy, javaScriptInterfaces);
    mDatabase = WebViewDatabaseClassic.getInstance(context);
    mScroller = new OverScroller(context, null, 0, 0, false); //TODO Use OverScroller's flywheel
    mZoomManager = new ZoomManager(this, mCallbackProxy);

    /* The init method must follow the creation of certain member variables,
     * such as the mZoomManager.
     */
    init();
    setupPackageListener(context);
    setupProxyListener(context);
    setupTrustStorageListener(context);
    updateMultiTouchSupport(context);

    if (privateBrowsing) {
        startPrivateBrowsing();
    }

    mAutoFillData = new WebViewCore.AutoFillData();
    mEditTextScroller = new Scroller(context);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Since you are interested about `mProvider` more than `init()` let's go through the path of `mProvider`.

First we see it defined in the WebView class.

```
private WebViewProvider mProvider;

private void ensureProviderCreated() {
    checkThread();
    if (mProvider == null) {
        // As this can get called during the base class constructor chain, pass the minimum
        // number of dependencies here; the rest are deferred to init().
        mProvider = getFactory().createWebView(this, new PrivateAccess());
    }
}
```

From the block above we can see that the `ensureProviderCreater()` method initializes the `mProvider` variable. This method is called in the non-deprecated constructor of the `WebView` class.

First the `getFactory()` method is called so let's look at that:

```
private static synchronized WebViewFactoryProvider getFactory() {
    // For now the main purpose of this function (and the factory abstration) is to keep
    // us honest and minimize usage of WebViewClassic internals when binding the proxy.
    checkThread();
    return WebViewFactory.getProvider();
}
```

Let's leave the `checkThread()` be and take a look at `WebViewFactory.getProvider();` instead.

```
static WebViewFactoryProvider getProvider() {
    synchronized (sProviderLock) {
        // For now the main purpose of this function (and the factory abstraction) is to keep
        // us honest and minimize usage of WebViewClassic internals when binding the proxy.
        if (sProviderInstance != null) return sProviderInstance;

        // For debug builds, we allow a system property to specify that we should use the
        // Chromium powered WebView. This enables us to switch between implementations
        // at runtime. For user (release) builds, don't allow this.
        if (Build.IS_DEBUGGABLE && SystemProperties.getBoolean("webview.use_chromium", false)) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy oldPolicy = StrictMode.allowThreadDiskReads();
            try {
                sProviderInstance = loadChromiumProvider();
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(LOGTAG, "Loaded Chromium provider: " + sProviderInstance);
            } finally {
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(oldPolicy);
            }
        }

        if (sProviderInstance == null) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(LOGTAG, "Falling back to default provider: "
                    + DEFAULT_WEBVIEW_FACTORY);
            sProviderInstance = getFactoryByName(DEFAULT_WEBVIEW_FACTORY,
                    WebViewFactory.class.getClassLoader());
            if (sProviderInstance == null) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(LOGTAG, "Falling back to explicit linkage");
                sProviderInstance = new WebViewClassic.Factory();
            }
        }
        return sProviderInstance;
    }
}
```

It may not be immediately obvious what is happening here but here's the jist of it.

It checks if the build is debug-enabled, if there is a system variable "webview.use_chromium" and if it's set to "true".

If all of the conditions above occur then the chromium webview provider gets loaded (for the reasons mentioned in the comments in the block above).

If the condition is not met (e.g. the build is not in devmode) we ask the class loader to load `DEFAULT_WEBVIEW_FACTORY` by name which actually resolves to `android.webkit.WebViewClassic$Factory` (Can you start to see it all coming together now? :) )

So in the end unless we're meeting some specific conditions `WebViewFactory.getProvider()` will return the inner `Factory` class of the `WebViewClassic` class - `WebViewClassic.Factory`.

So let's revert back to our initial `ensureProviderCreated()` and see where we stand at the moment.

```
private void ensureProviderCreated() {
    checkThread();
    if (mProvider == null) {
        // As this can get called during the base class constructor chain, pass the minimum
        // number of dependencies here; the rest are deferred to init().
        mProvider = getFactory().createWebView(this, new PrivateAccess());
    }
}
```

OK, so we now know that `getFactory()` will return `WebViewClassic.Factory`, so now we only need to inspect the `createWebView` method of that factory.

```
@Override
public WebViewProvider createWebView(WebView webView, WebView.PrivateAccess privateAccess) {
    return new WebViewClassic(webView, privateAccess);
}
```

As you can plainly see it is quite straightforward, it returns a new instance of `WebViewClassic` passing it the `WebView` object since we called it from `WebView` with `this` as well as the `privateAccess` argument will be the `new PrivateAccess()` we passed as well.

For completion sake here's the constructor that is called for `WebViewClassic`:

```
public WebViewClassic(WebView webView, WebView.PrivateAccess privateAccess) {
    mWebView = webView;
    mWebViewPrivate = privateAccess;
    mContext = webView.getContext();
}
```

Hopefully this should clear up your confusion about what the heck is `mProvider` and how is it made. :)

Comment: Not able to find the string "mProvider" in http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/webkit/WebViewClassic.java/?v=source. Even it is present how does that fit in **WebView**(Where the object created.? Where is the declaration of mProvider?. What is the type?)

Comment: @Talespin_Kit updated my answer with a more elaborate explanation. :)

Comment: To directly answer your comment questions: `mProvider` is a variable name in the `WebView` class so you will not find the string in `WebViewClassic`, `WebView` creates a new `WebViewClassic` object in the `ensureProviderCreated` method and assigns it to the `mProvider` variable (since `WebViewClassic` implements `WebViewProvider` this is allowed), the declaration of the `mProvider` variable is just above the `ensureProviderCreated` method in the `WebView` class somewhere around the line number 1856.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer. The declaration was right there in the file, i guess i got too much used to ide finding the declarations and missed out to find out manually :)